# What's the best way to compress multiple values into deserializable value?

Tags: algorithm, dart, compression

I'm implementing an [openpeeps.com](https://www.openpeeps.com/) library for Flutter in which user can create their own peeps to use as an avatar within our product.

One of the reasons behind using peeps as avatar is that (in theory) it can be easily stored as a single value within a database.

A `Peep` within my library contains of up to 6 `PeepAtoms`:

```
class Peep {
  final PeepAtom head;
  final PeepAtom face;
  final PeepAtom facialHair;
  final PeepAtom? accessories;
  final PeepAtom? body;
  final PeepAtom? pose;
}
```

A `PeepAtom` is currently just a name identifying the underlying image file required to build a `Peep`:

```
class PeepAtom {
  final String name;
}
```

**How to get a hash?**

What I'd like to do now is get a single value from a `Peep` (`int` or `string`) which I can store in a database. If I retrieve the data, I'd like to deconstruct the value into the unique atoms so I can render the appropriate atom images to display the Peep. While I'm not really looking to optimize for storage size, it would be nice if the bytesize would be small.

Since I'm normally not working with such stuff I don't have an idea what's the best option. These are my (naïve) ideas:

- do a `Peep.toJson` and convert the output to `base64`. Likely inefficient due to a bunch of unnecessary characters.
- do a `PeepAtom.hashCode` for each field within a `Peep` and upload this. As an array that would be 64bit = 8 Byte * 6 (Atoms). Thats pretty ok but not a single value.
- since there are only a limited number of Atoms in each category (less than 100) I could use bitshifts and `^` to put this into one int. However, I think this would not really working because I'd need a unique identifier and since I'm code generating the `PeepAtom`s within my code that likely would be quite complex.

Any better ideas/algorithms?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me before what you were trying to do.  You want to reconstruct the objects (which you no longer have) from some simple type.  Hashes by definition are one-way, so you don't actually want anything "hash-like".  You want a serialization/deserialization solution.  If each category has at most 100 unique values, then you have at most 100^6 possible values, which would fit in a 64-bit integer.  You then could use the value of each "digit" in the serialized base-100 form as an index into an appropriate list of `PeepAtom`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "quite complex". It looks quite simple to pack your atoms into a double.

Note that this is no way a "hash". A hash is a lossy operation. I presume that you want to recover the original data.

Based on your description, you need seven bits for each atom. They can range in 0..98 (since you said "less than 100"). A double has 52 bits of mantissa. Your six atoms needs 42 bits, so it fits easily. For atoms that can be `null`, just give that a special unused 7-bit value, like 127.

Now just use multiply and add to combine them. Use modulo and divide to pull them back out. E.g.:

```
double val = head;
val = val * 128 + face;
val = val * 128 + facialHair;
...
```

To extract:

```
int pose = val % 128;
val = (val / 128).floorToDouble();
int body = val % 128;
val = (val / 128).floorToDouble();
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I was overcomplicating stuff. I indeed implemented it kind of like this but I find it quite confusing to serialize the values to a double. I think and integer and using bit-shifts makes more sense.

Comment: The reason I chose a double is that you don't have a reliable 64-bit integer. Java does its bit operations on 32-bit values. You specifically said "single value". If you're happy with _two_ values, you can put your stuff in two 32-bit integers with bit-shifts.